# How to run docker exec using Java on a docker container

Tags: java, bash, shell, docker

I have a docker container called `pps-control`. If I want to execute a script that lives inside the container which for this example takes 1 arg, I do from my linux terminal:

> docker exec pps-control /bin/sh -c "./build/doControlStuff.sh 123456"

My question is: **How do I achieve doing the same using java code?**
I know that there is something like:

```
package com.mypackage;
import static com.palantir.docker.compose.execution.DockerComposeExecArgument.arguments;
import static com.palantir.docker.compose.execution.DockerComposeExecOption.options;
import com.palantir.docker.compose.DockerComposeRule;

public class TestClass {
    public static DockerComposeRule docker;
    public static void testMethod() {
        docker.exec(options(), "pps-control", arguments("bash", "-c", "./build/doControlStuff.sh 123456"));
    }
}
```

But haven't been able to figure out how to use it (with correct syntax), any help would be appreciated with **actual code** example, thanks!

```
My Docker version is 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
```

Comment: What problem are you having? What version of Docker are you using? What is `option` and `args`?

Comment: @dpwrussell, Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @dpwrussell: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @dpwrussell: caused by `ReflectiveCallable.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace

Comment: @dpwrussell: I only get java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.mypackage.TestClass.testMethod(TestClass.java:9)

Comment: Hi, were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: @user1147070 - Yes I did by doing following:

    `private static DockerComposeExecOption option = DockerComposeExecOption.noOptions();`
...
    `DockerComposeExecArgument args = DockerComposeExecArgument.arguments("bash", "-c", "./build/doControlStuff.sh 123456");`
...
    `docker.exec(option, "pps-control", args);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your last argument should be “\”build/doControlStuff.sh 123456\””.